# Google Drive : File Uploading and Accessing the files

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Can anyone help me the google drive [long term validity] refresh token,

1. Refresh token getting expired every week, we wanted to fix and the refresh token permanently.
2. Google project status is internal,[application status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTkwF.png)
3. using Laravel package : nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive
4. Using Laravel Application.

Please Help me through this,
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Refresh token getting expired every week, we wanted to fix and the refresh token permanently.

Applications in the testing phase will expire after a week.  Set your project to production and your refresh token will be unlimited.  You may also have to have it verified.

[oauth2#expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

[image]

Unfortunately the statement that it only effects external user type is untrue.  All testing by me and others currently shows that even internal apps must be set to production or a refresh token will expire.  I have an email out to the Oauth team to either get the documentation fixed or to get it fixed so that it doesnt expire i am waiting to hear back.